# ADB2C - Getting Error when trying to login: serverError: server_error: AADB2C90027: There was a problem processing your request. Please try again

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am utilizing ADB2C to register and manage users within my application, also hosted on Azure. The redirect to the login page is working fine but when I hit login or try to create an account, i am hit with the below error:

> core.mjs:6485 ERROR ServerError: server_error: AADB2C90027: There was a problem processing your request. Please try again. Correlation ID: e5362df2-287c-403a-8de4-0a77c2fbbc08Timestamp: 2022-10-04 07:52:10Z
> at ServerError.AuthError [as constructor] (AuthError.js:27:1)

note - I managed to get this working on a separate cluster with the same configurations. I'm not sure what I may have missed

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error **`AADB2C90027`**, usually occurs if credentials specified are invalid. Make sure to pass valid credentials which have access granted by the resource.

I configured **Azure AD B2C Application** like below:

[image]

**I am able to create an account successfully like below:**

[image]

If the error persists, you can configure an API connector to validate the user information:

[image]

- The error server_error: **`AADB2C90027`**: There was a problem processing your request usually occurs if the web server is not configured properly to the application.
- Please check whether the sign-up policy name is missing or configured correctly in your **`Web.config`** file for the application.
- If the issue still persists, recreate the application and check if it creates the account.